# Why duration not write in logfile?

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 14.
My Postgres conf:

```
logging_collector = on  
log_min_duration_statement = 400
log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_duration = off
log_line_prefix = '%Q %r %d ' #%Q = query ID %r = remote host and port %d = database name
log_statement = 'all'
```

And i get log:

```
2022-06-24 10:08:36.668 UTC [92] LOG:  statement: 
                    UPDATE ***
                    SET ****
                    WHERE ***
```

Why it not have 'duration'?
I want get log:

```
2022-06-24 10:08:36.668 UTC [92] LOG: duration: 5944.540 ms statement: 
                    UPDATE ***
                    SET ****
                    WHERE ***
```

Comment: I assume `log_duration = off` is actually `log_duration = on` and not the mistake?

Comment: if i do ```log_duration = on```, in my logfile  writed all queryes, but i want write queryes only duration more then 400ms ```log_min_duration_statement = 400```

Comment: With your current settings, the statement text is logged when it is received, but the duration is not logged until the statement finished, and does not log the statement text again as it was already logged.  If the server is busy, those log lines might be far apart from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `log_statement = 'none'`, then all statements running for more than 0.4 seconds will be logged along with their duration.

Comment: no, it doesn't work. Nothing is written to the log file

Comment: I mean, leave all the other settings as you show them.

Comment: No, it doesn`t work(

Comment: Well, I cannot reproduce that.